# e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am getting the following error when trying to run my project in android studio. Additionally it shows me the following **Cannot access 'AppCompatActivity' which is a supertype of 'MyClass'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies**.
The project is working fine until I integrated firebase. At this time when removing dependencies from firebase the error keeps appearing.

Gradle(App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
    }

    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "innobile.itraceandroid"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testApplicationId "innobile.itraceandroid.tests"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {

    }
    productFlavors {
    }


}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.8.0-beta4'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.4.2'
    implementation 'net.steamcrafted:load-toast:1.0.12'
    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.2'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.5.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    //OkHttp
    implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.12"){
        force = true //API 19 support
    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.12'
}
```

Gradle buil (project)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.20'
    repositories {

        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can you add the signature of the `MyClass`?

Comment: Sure. **innobile.itraceandroid.Inventory**

Comment: I mean the like where you wrote MyClass extends ..... which class it is?